# How to populate a readonly collection of interfaces

Tags: c#, unit-testing, collections

I have a task that I have to complete where I need to get the following unit test (which I can't modify) to pass.

```
[Test]
public void TheJarShouldContain30SweetsWhenCreated()
{
    IJarOfSweetsCreator jarOfSweetsCreator = new JarOfSweetsCreator();
    IJarOfSweets jarOfSweets = jarOfSweetsCreator.Create();
    const int expectedNumberOfSweets = 30;
    int numberOfSweets = jarOfSweets.Count;

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedNumberOfSweets, numberOfSweets);
}
```

Although it is not much to go on, `JarOfSweetsCreator` has this code:

```
public class JarOfSweetsCreator : IJarOfSweetsCreator
{
    public IJarOfSweets Create()
    {

        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and `IJarOfSweets` has this:

```
public interface IJarOfSweets : IReadOnlyCollection<ISweet>
{
    void Shuffle ();
    ISweet TakeSweetFromJar ();
}
```

I need to make the test pass by creating and counting 30 from `IJarOfSweets`.  I don't understand how to create and count 30 instances of an interface, if you can only have one but I know that sounds daft.

I am assuming it has something to do with the `IReadOnlyCollection<ISweet>` part of the `IJarOfSweets` interface but I don't know how to use it. Is `IJarOfSweets` used like a collection or would I create a collection within this interface?

If it is a read only collection, how am I supposed to make 30 of them?

Comment: " Is IJarOfSweets used like a collection" - yes, that's why it implements `IReadOnlyCollection<ISweet>`... It's meant to be used as a collection of sweets, although oddly enough with a `Shuffle` method as well. To be honest, if you're having trouble with this it might be best to ask your teacher for more details, as it suggests you may have missed some concepts.

Comment: Ok but then how would I create 30 if the collection is read only?

Comment: IReadOnlyCollection is a bad name - the interface only exposes members to read the collection rather than mutating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, the best thing to do is to write the minimum amount of code that you can in order to get your tests to pass.  This helps you to reflect on your tests and ensures that you're writing useful tests.

As it stands, your test requires a few things from you.  It needs you to implement the `Create` method of `JarOfSweetsCreator` to return something that implements `IJarOfSweets` and it requires the returned object to return 30 when you check it's `Count` property.

The first step is to create a concrete class `JarOfSweets`, that implements the interface. The method that *needs* to do anything is the `Count` property, so the class would look like this:

```
public class JarOfSweets : IJarOfSweets {
    public void Shuffle()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public ISweet TakeSweetFromJar()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    int IReadOnlyCollection<ISweet>.Count
    {
        get { return 30; }
    }

    IEnumerator<ISweet> IEnumerable<ISweet>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then you need to update the creator to return a new instance of the `JarOfSweets` class.

```
public class JarOfSweetsCreator : IJarOfSweetsCreator
{
    public IJarOfSweets Create()
    {

        return new JarOfSweets();
    }
}
```

That's the *minimum* that needs to be done to get the test to pass.  In reality, you're likely to want to do a bit more with the code going forward as you write more tests / write code to get tests to pass.

As Jon has said in the comments, the `ReadOnlyCollection`, just tells you that `JarOfSweets` needs to implement certain functions (get count + get enumerator).  It doesn't mean that the collection actually needs to be *readonly*.  You can implement it using any of the built in collection types, or you can write your own.

It's important to remember that when you know the concrete type that is implementing the interface, you also have access to methods, not defined on the interface.  So, in your `JarOfSweetsCreator` for example it will need to know the `JarOfSweets` actual implementation type, rather than just the interface in order to instantiate it.  This means that it is possible for the `Create` method to call other methods on your underlying collection, like an `Add` method.  So, assuming that you have a `Sweet` class that implements `ISweet` you could end up with a creator that looks a bit more like this:

```
public class JarOfSweetsCreator : IJarOfSweetsCreator
{
    public IJarOfSweets Create()
    {

        var jar = new JarOfSweets();

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            jar.Add(new Sweet());
        }

        return jar;
    }
}
```

And then in your `JarOfSweets`, it could simply use a `List<T>` and delegate the relevant functions:

```
public class JarOfSweets : IJarOfSweets{
    public List<ISweet> _list = new List<ISweet>();

    public void Shuffle()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public ISweet TakeSweetFromJar()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Add(Sweet sweet)
    {
        _list.Add(sweet);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _list.Count; }
    }

    public IEnumerator<ISweet> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _list.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _list.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Its a good idea that I will use if I dont get another answer as, although I only mentioned one unit test, I have other tests such as checking wether the sweets are all different colours etc. I didnt mention them as I thought that I could give them a go myself after getting help setting up the collection.

Comment: @LouiseEvans I've added an alternative that might be a bit more helpful with your actual implementation...Notice that the Creator can add things to the list, because It's not accessing it via the readonly interface, it knows the concrete type and all of it's available functions.